# Automatically scroll to the first div containing the matched image

Tags: jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

I have a div container which has about 9 rows in it.

Each row has a different picture.

I'm attempting to scroll down to the first row which has a certain image by referencing the image path.

I'm attempting this by using scrollTop with offset as so:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('img[src="../resources/images/icons/grey/checklist/new.png"]').offset().top});
```

There exists 2 rows which contain the same new.png image.

I want it to stop scrolling as soon as it finds the first div with that image path, instead it scrolls straight to the bottom.

Does anyone know what I am missing or where I am going wrong? Thank you for your time.

Edit:

I forgot to mention that the the html structure of the page is created using a handlebars template and the images are dynamically populated, so I am only looking out for particular images, and assumed I could do so by referencing image paths for new.png images.

Comment: This link may helpful  https://paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery

Comment: Post the relevant HTML too.

Comment: Why don't you set IDs for the images and scroll to the image with the desired ID?

Comment: its the demo page https://paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/jquery_internal_animation_scrolling/

Comment: Are you waiting for document.ready before calling the animate?